# How to remove city field from order in dashboard?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

i need to remove city field and one of payment method anyone know how ?
  [image: order details woocommerce]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put that code in function.php or in plugin file .

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'unset_order_city_field' );

function unset_order_city_field( $billing_fields ){  
  unset($billing_fields['city']); 
  return $billing_fields;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, your answer was automatically flagged as low quality. You can avoid this type of automatic flag in the future by adding a description to you answers regarding what the code does, what the variables in the code hold, where to add the code, and how the code solves the original issue. You may [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/313504/edit) at any time using the `edit` button above.